# grouping array keys in JS

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
{ 
  'coinRow[0][txID]': 'btc',
  'coinRow[0][amountSpent]': '0.33',
  'coinRow[0][date]': '28/7/18',
  'coinRow[1][txID]': 'btc',
  'coinRow[1][amountSpent]': '0.23',
  'coinRow[1][date]': '28/7/18' 
}
```

I want to arrange this in an object so every index will be grouped together

```
[{
    txID: 'btc',
    amountSpent: 0.33,
    date: '28/7/18'
},{
    txID: 'ven',
    amountSpent: 0.23,
    date: '28/7/18'
}]
```

Thank you!

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have tried to use array reduce like so:

     data = Array.from(data.entries()).reduce((memo,pair) => (
            {
            ...memo,
            [pair[0]]: pair[1]
        }), {})
  But the keys comes in the [pair[0]] as a string so it does not look at it as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting a value, you could split the path and reduce the keys by walking the given object. If no object exist, create a new property with the name, or an array. Later assign the value.

This approach works for nested arrays as well.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var keys = path.replace(/\[/g, '.').replace(/\]/g, '').split('.'),
        last = keys.pop();

    keys.reduce((o, k, i, a) =>
        o[k] = o[k] || (isFinite(i + 1 in a ? a[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {}),
        object
    )[last] = value;
    return object;
}

var data = { 'coinRow[0][txID]': 'btc', 'coinRow[0][amountSpent]': '0.33', 'coinRow[0][date]': '28/7/18', 'coinRow[1][txID]': 'btc', 'coinRow[1][amountSpent]': '0.23', 'coinRow[1][date]': '28/7/18' },
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .reduce((o, [k, v]) => setValue(o, k, v), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries` to convert the object into an array. Use `reduce` to summarize the array into an object. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array.

```js
var obj = {
  'coinRow[0][txID]': 'btc',
  'coinRow[0][amountSpent]': '0.33',
  'coinRow[0][date]': '28/7/18',
  'coinRow[1][txID]': 'btc',
  'coinRow[1][amountSpent]': '0.23',
  'coinRow[1][date]': '28/7/18'
};

var result = Object.values(Object.entries(obj).reduce((c, [k, v]) => {
  k = k.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g).map(o => o.slice(1, -1));
  c[k[0]] = c[k[0]] || {};
  c[k[0]][k[1]] = v;
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

---

If your first index is a sequence number from 0 - N, You can init the `reduce` with empty array and no need for `Object.values`

```js
var obj = {
  'coinRow[0][txID]': 'btc',
  'coinRow[0][amountSpent]': '0.33',
  'coinRow[0][date]': '28/7/18',
  'coinRow[1][txID]': 'btc',
  'coinRow[1][amountSpent]': '0.23',
  'coinRow[1][date]': '28/7/18'
};

var result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((c, [k, v]) => {
  k = k.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g).map(o => o.slice(1, -1));
  c[k[0]] = c[k[0]] || {};
  c[k[0]][k[1]] = v;
  return c;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```